# Format for recording RGB color in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, format

React client is sending color to my server with this format
 `{"r":1 "g":8 "b":5 "a":2}`, for instance.

I'm not sure what is the best way to record color in MySQL.

I don't want to use this data in server. Just I want to send it to the client with the same format.

Comment: Further to the first comment, how are you filtering/joining/sorting/grouping by r,g,b values? Are you doing maths operations on them?

Answer (score 3):

If "you want to send it to the client with the same format", then it is reasonable to treat it as "opaque".

That is, store it as a string with no meaning or structure that you care about.  And it does not matter (within limits) what datatype you use.  `VARCHAR(99)`, `TEXT`, `BLOB` -- any of these would suffice.